# How can I show my Paypal Express shortcut button on a configurable product page?

Tags: product, configurable-product, paypal, paypal-express, products-view

My PayPal express shortcut button is showing on my simple products but for some reason will not show (on the product view page) for my configurable product.

Within the file `/app/design/frontend/default/MY-TEMPLATE/template/catalog/product/view/addtocart.phtml` the following line is not being pulled in.

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('', true, true) ?>
```

I'm not entirely sure which file this calls directly but it does enable `/app/design/frontend/default/asd/template/paypal/express/shortcut.phtml` which is the one I want.

Perhaps PayPal express is not set-up to facilitate product variations that can be changed on screen but that doesn't make a huge amount of sense. If someone can please help or comment that would appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that the paypal express checkout will work on configurable products directly.
When clicking on the express checkout link, you have to sent a product id as a parameter, and the configurable product id does not have meaning on its own. It needs the configurable attributes selected, and only after that the configurable product is "translated" to a simple product that can be ordered.